# Trying to connect my SNES to new TV using RF cable - can't get it to auto tune or manual tune

Tags: monitor, snes

Whenever I select auto tune it just goes through 0% - 100% and finishes saying it didn't detect anything and to check the antenna connection. With manual tune, there is 'DTV' or 'TV'. In DTV, I have the option to change UHF CH. and there is an indicator (of signal strength I guess?) which is labelled 'Bad' 'Normal' 'Good' and then 'Add' 'Close' below it. 'Add' is greyed out on UHF CH. I try so I guess it doesn't detect anything?

On 'TV' there is 'Storage'  'System' 'Band' 'Channel' 'Search' 'Name' 'Store' and 'Close'. I'm guessing the answer is somewhere in 'TV'? Anyone know how to tune this? The alternative is that the cartidge isn't working (tried cleaning it) or the console is broken. Or the RF just won't work on my TV, I haven't got AV cables but I'll get them if none of you can help. Thanks

Comment: Got a VCR? And it is under Analog not digital(T.V not DTV).

Comment: RF switches use channels 3 or 4, which are VHF not UHF.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tune it manually to Chanel 3 or 4